# Prevent voice over (Accessibility) from announcing UITableViewCell as selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

When a UITableViewCell is selected, voice over announces "**selected**", I don't want voice over to say "selected". How can i achieve this ?

**Things I have tried with no success:**

- Changed the cell `accessibilityHint` and `accessibilityLabel`
- Changed the cell `selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`
- changed the cell `accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton`

**Question:**

- I don't want voice over to say "selected" when a cell is selected. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: prevent voice over means ?

Comment: I don't want voice over to say "selected" when a cell is selected

Comment: Does anyone have a sane answer to this?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The only work around is prevent cell selection

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    return nil;
}
```

Add a Tap gesture on the cell and when the cell is tapped, do the what ever you want in cell selection inside the tap gesture.

Comment: The proper way to solve this is to create a custom UITableViewCell and override its accessibilityTraits var as I have posted in my answer.

Answer (score 16):

I asked this as a code level support issue from Apple and got the following solution which works perfectly. Use a custom subclass of UITableViewCell where you override accessibilityTraits as in the following example:

```
class NoTraitCell: UITableViewCell {
    override var accessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraits {
        get {
            return UIAccessibilityTraitNone
        }
        set {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try by deselecting the cell again:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom cell class and override `accessibilityTraits` like this:

```
- (UIAccessibilityTraits)accessibilityTraits {
     return UIAccessibilityTraitButton;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to use the selection feature of the tableview then don't use `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. I know I've always used this as a "didTapOnRowAt" method, but a better way is to use `willSelectRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    // code for when a row is tapped
    return nil
}
```

The `return nil` means the cell won't actually be selected.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to set the cell's `accessibilityLabel` to `" "` (empty string doesn't work) on `didSelectRow()`, trigger a reload, then reset `accessibilityLabel` on next dequeue.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `accessibilityElementsHidden` property for disabling voice accessibility.

If you don't want to hear a view in voice-over mode set the `accessibilityElementsHidden` property to `true` for that particular view([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615080-accessibilityelementshidden))

In your case, for a `UITableViewCell` you can set it as true in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // write code to create cell ....
    cell.accessibilityElementsHidden = true
    return cell
}
```

Note: You can also set the property in `awakeFromNib()` method for a custom class table view cell.

Comment: I want VoiceOver to read the text in the cell, but not to announce "Selected", which annoys users.